# Can groovy heredocs be internationalized?

Tags: groovy, internationalization, heredoc

Have some multiline strings that are presented to the user and stored as Heredocs.  So rather than a 'normal' (Java) property file, a groovy-based one (see [here](http://geekmatt.blogspot.com/2010/09/use-configsluper-instead-of-properites.html)) to be consumed by ConfigSlurper was used and works great.  Sorry if this is a dumb question, but can that be easily internationalized?  If so, can you outline how that is accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried [i18n in Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Internationalization) yet?

Comment: If I do that (which very well might be the best option!), I think I have to do this for multi-line properties:                        `prop1=first line of prop1 \  
    second line of prop1\  
    third line of prop1`

Comment: Sorry, can't make the above comment 'look' right on multiple lines - hopefully you understand that would be a 3 line example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the `ConfigSlurper` does not have special support for i18n.
You may achieve it by using the leveraging its support for [environments](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper) by creating an environment closure per locale. For example:

```
environments {
  english {
    sample {
      hello = "hello"
    }
  }
  spanish {
    sample {
      hello = "hola"
    }
  }
}
```

When creating the `ConfigSlurper` you will need to pass the desired language:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper("spanish")
```

Comment: I think this would 'work', but isn't very desirable as the settings for all the languages (locales) would need to be in the same file...

Comment: you can split them between multiple files and merge them all into a single configuration (supported by ConfigSlurper)

Comment: Hi - I am selecting this as the 'answer' even though I am not very happy with it - I would hope that the property extensions Groovy adds implied by ConfigSlurper would be extended to provide more natural support of I18N...

Answer (score 1):

My solution: In your `ConfigSlurper` you should store **keys** to the internalized strings. Inject `messageSource`and `localResolver` in your controller/service, get key from your `ConfigSlurper` and find localized string in your **i18n** messages.property file. Example (not sure that code is correct, but it's the main idea):

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('src/Config.groovy').toURL())

//localized string1 value
def msg = messageSource.getMessage(config.data1.string1, null, localeResolver.defaultLocale)
```

Comment: If I follow this correctly, then I would not be able to use heredoc's but would need regular property files with the multi-line values with the trailing backslashes.  Is that correct?